# VSTS Checkout Submodules is not working

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have 2repos. Repo1 is dependent on repo2.

I tried the following steps:

1. Git clone repo1
2. git submodule add repo2
3. uploaded the .gitmodules file in VSTS of repo1 branch
4. In Get-sources step of VSTS build, clicked on check-out submodules
5. Added one extra step git submodule update --init.

Still the submodules files are not getting into agent. below is my .gitmodules
[submodule "sm"] path = sm url = https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_git/sm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s caused by **you didn’t commit and push the `sm` (repo2 name) in repo1**.

After you add repo2 (sm) as submodule  for repo1 (`git submodule add <URL for repo2>`), there will create two files need to be committed:

- `.gitmodules`: record the path and source to get the submodule repo (repo2).
- `sm` (repo2 name): record the commit which you added the submodule repo (repo2) in repo1

**These two files are both necessary for submodule**. While you only uploaded `.gitmodules` in VSTS repo1, so even you cloned the repo1 with submodule (in Get sources step), git can’t find the commit which you add the submodule.

The correct way is commit and push the two files.

If you haven’t made other changes on the local repo after add submodule and no other change on repo1, you can use way to commit and push:

```
git status #make sure both the .gitmodules and sm (repo2 name) are staged (changes to be committed)
git commit -m 'commit for .gitmodules and sm (repo2 name)'
git push -f #force push
```

Comment: Hi Marina. What do you mean by sm here. Is my repo2 folder becomes sm here? or there is will be another file named sm. But I couldn't find any sm file or folder under my branch/local.

Comment: When you add repo2 as submodule for repo1, there will create a folder name `sm` and a file `.gitmodules`, you should commit/push both of them, and the `sm` will exist as a file in VSTS with the commit id as content.

Comment: Hi Marina. Can you help me offline. can you provide your skype id/fb id/mail?

Comment: Sorry, personal address is not allowed here. We can discuss the issue in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153091/vsts-submodule this room.

Comment: Sorry for that. I don't have 20 reputation to chat over there . I didn't get any file named sm when I ran git submodule add repo2

Comment: Oh, so did you make changes after adding submodule in your local repo? And what's the `git status` say in your local repo?

Comment: I didn't change any files. My git status shows .gitmodules and repo2 name as a new file

Comment: If you also changed nothing in VSTS after uploading the `.gitmodule`, you can use the commands: `git add  .`, `git commit -m 'add submodule'` and `git push -f `. Then the submodule is pushed to repo1 correctly.

Comment: And isn't your repo2 name `sm`? But based on the contents in `.gitmodules` (last part in your question), it seems the repo2's name is `sm`.

Comment: If I do git add . my repo2 also gets commited. I checked all the files in my local branch and I don't see any file named as sm.

Comment: It should be the **folder** with repo2 name in local repo. Then you can force push to VSTS, you will find the **file** with repo2 name is added in VSTS.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem. And I updated my answer to explain the `sm` as repo2 name so that it can be better understand. And can you mark the answer since the question has been solved? It can benefit others who have similar questions :)

Comment: I tried to mark the answer, but it is not recording as my reputation is below 15

Comment: It's not reputation related, you just need to click the check mark symbol (√) on the left of the answer.

Comment: One more quick question.  Rep02 contains bin and obj which are not even mentioned in my branch of .gitingore, but when I add submodule the bin folder and obj folder are not coming into submodule of repo1. I checked in my .gitingore with empty content, but after adding submodule some content is coming in .gitignore

Comment: If `.gitignore` in repo2 is empty, please check the `.gitigore` in repo1. If the `.gitignore` contains `bin` and `obj`, the submodule will also ignore `bin` and `obj`. You can change it as detail relative path for which is need to ignore or you can you `!/relative/path/to/bin/or/obj` to exclude bin and obj in this path.